# formsubmit: after submitting the form, it redirect me to a page with this message in red fonts: "Whoops, looks like something went wrong". Any Advice

Tags: forms, post, action

Submiting mt form I get this error:
"Whoops, looks like something went wrong"

Inspecting the console provides this info:
POST https://formsubmit.co/el/confirm/66fef0a08bce40a01cf0e98b199694cd 405

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: some issue, how did you solve it?